# Integral involving Heaviside function in the exponential

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to compute the following integral in the real domain that involves the Heaviside step function $\Theta(x)$:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{- \alpha_0\Theta(x)- \alpha_1 x} dx
$$

with $\alpha_0, \alpha_1$ two real constants.
Is there some useful representation of the Heaviside $\Theta$ function that I can exploit to calculate the integral?

Or should I compute the integral using some complex plane technique?

Comment: Well, the step function is $+1$ on your entire domain of integration, so this is just $e^{-\alpha_0} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha_1 x} \, dx$....

Comment: Yes, use the definition of that function.